# Игра "Память" на Javascript, сравнение карточек (значений переменных)

Tags: javascript, jquery, сравнение

Добрый день! Недавно начала изучать JS, при написании игры столкнулась с проблемой: каким образом в данном случае можно сравнить открываемые карточки (значения переменных guess1 и guess2)? Мой код (ниже) не работает - вероятно, потому что я не совсем понимаю, какие значения получают переменные при клике на ячейки. По стандартным правилам игры при открытии одинаковых карточек они должны остаться открытыми, в противном случае - закрыться. [JS Bin ссылка с полным кодом](https://jsbin.com/miwogogiwa/edit?)

```
for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
var imageUrl = images + gameArray[i * columns + j] + '.png';
 $('<td></td>')
   .css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')')
   .appendTo(row);
}
}
```

*

```
$('td').click(function() {
var guess1 = $(this);
guess1.removeClass('closed');
var guess2 = $(this);
guess2.removeClass('closed');
if (guess1 != guess2) {
 $('guess1').attr("class", "closed");
 $('guess2').attr("class", "closed");
}
});
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что `guess1` и `guess2` в данном случае получают одинаковые значения.

Comment: @EugenEray но ведь клики происходят по разным ячейкам с разными .css - можно ли каким-то образом сравнивать такие вот свойства?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не усложняйте себе работу - просто добавьте `data-value` и держите там значения:

```js
var clicksCount = 0;

$(document).on('click', '.card-container div', function() {
  let display = $('.card-container div.display');
  let thisCell = $(this);
  // если индекс отображаемого элемента === индексу нажатого - выходим
  if (display.index() === thisCell.index())
    return;
    
  // считаем кол-во кликов
  clicksCount++;

  // если уже есть открытые - закрой всех
  if (display.length > 0) {
    display.removeClass('display');
  }
  // если data-value у текущего и открытого совпадает - пометь обоих как решенные
  if (display.data('value') === thisCell.data('value')) {
    thisCell.addClass('solved');
    display.addClass('solved');
    // иначе - покажи и после 2 сек закрой
  } else {
    thisCell.addClass('display');
    setTimeout(function() {
      thisCell.removeClass('display')
    }, 2000);
  }

  // если кол-во решенных === кол-ву всего - задача решена
  if ($('.card-container div.solved').length === $('.card-container div').length) {
    alert('Solved!\nTotal clicks: ' + clicksCount);
  }
});

// тут мы просто генерим потомков контейнера
$(function() {
  let shuffle = function(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length; i; i--) {
      j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
      x = a[i - 1];
      a[i - 1] = a[j];
      a[j] = x;
    }
  }

  let values = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    values.push(i);
    values.push(i);
  }
  shuffle(values);
  values.forEach(function(v) {
    $('.card-container').append('<div data-value="' + v + '">' + v + '</div>');
  });
})
```

```css
.card-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 408px;
  height: 408px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.card-container div {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card-container div.display {
  text-indent: 0%;
}

.card-container div.solved {
  text-indent: 0%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card-container"></div>
```

Вариант с сравнением картинок:

```js
var clicksCount = 0;
var imagesData = [
  'http://www.zooclub.ru/skat/img.php?w=700&h=700&img=./attach/5762.jpg',
  'http://www.zooclub.ru/skat/img.php?w=700&h=700&img=./attach/12000/12669.jpg',
  'http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/1366x768/2005/Animals_Cats__001795_1.jpg',
  'http://mirgif.com/humor/prikol104.jpg',
  'http://www.sunhome.ru/i/wallpapers/200/planeta-zemlya-kartinka.960x540.jpg',
  'http://www.cruzo.net/user/images/k/prv/dbb025264e7d1a35772dfa4387514de9_172.jpg',
  'http://minionomaniya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD.jpg',
  'https://img1.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/big/d/63/foto-kartinka-art-stil-domo.jpg'
];

$(document).on('click', '.card-container div', function() {
  let display = $('.card-container div').not('.hidden').not('.solved');
  let thisCell = $(this);
  // если индекс отображаемого элемента === индексу нажатого - выходим
  if (thisCell.hasClass('solved') || display.index() === thisCell.index())
    return;

  // считаем кол-во кликов
  clicksCount++;

  // если уже есть открытые - закрой всех
  if (display.length > 0) {
    display.addClass('hidden');
  }
  // если data-value у текущего и открытого совпадает - пометь обоих как решенные
  if (display.data('value') === thisCell.data('value')) {
    thisCell.removeClass('hidden');
    thisCell.addClass('solved');
    display.removeClass('hidden');
    display.addClass('solved');
    // иначе - покажи и после 2 сек закрой
  } else {
    thisCell.removeClass('hidden');
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (thisCell.hasClass('solved'))
        return;
      thisCell.addClass('hidden')
    }, 2000);
  }

  // если кол-во решенных === кол-ву всего - задача решена
  if ($('.card-container div.solved').length === $('.card-container div').length) {
    alert('Solved!\nTotal clicks: ' + clicksCount);
  }
});

// тут мы просто генерим потомков контейнера
$(function() {
  let shuffle = function(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length; i; i--) {
      j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
      x = a[i - 1];
      a[i - 1] = a[j];
      a[j] = x;
    }
  }

  let values = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < imagesData.length; i++) {
    values.push(i);
    values.push(i);
  }
  shuffle(values);
  values.forEach(function(v) {
    let div = $('<div data-value="' + v + '"></div>');
    div.css('background-image', 'url(' + imagesData[v] + ')');
    div.addClass('hidden');
    $('.card-container').append(div);
  });
})
```

```css
.card-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 408px;
  height: 408px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.card-container div {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.card-container div.hidden {
  background-image: none !important;
}

.card-container div.solved {
  text-indent: 0%;
  color: white;
}

.card-background-image {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card-container"></div>
```

Comment: Это очень здорово, спасибо, разобралась! А все же с изначальным кодом можно сделать что-то, чтобы работала проверка? Мне любопытно, возможно ли это с исходными данными / возможно ли сравнение значений атрибутов background-image у td-шек, ведь именно ими они отличаются.

Comment: @edithpifpaf добавил вариант с картинками

Comment: спасибо за идею, разобралась со своим кодом благодаря ей!)

Comment: @edithpifpaf добавьте может ссылку на реализацию прокомментировать ваше решение :)

Comment: добавила решение отдельным ответом :)

Comment: имеет право на существование мой вариант али кривовато?)

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, все же решила не переписывать код, а разобраться в уже написанном - решила проблему сравнения карточек следующим образом:

```
var paused = false;
$('#game').on('click', 'td', function() {
  if (paused) {
    return false;
  }

  var thisCell = $(this);
  if (thisCell.hasClass('matched')) {
    return false;
  } else {
    thisCell.toggleClass('closed');
  }

  var openCards = $('#game td').not('.closed').not('.matched');
  if (openCards.length === 2) {
    var cardA = openCards.eq(0);
    var cardB = openCards.eq(1);
    if (cardA.css('background-image') === cardB.css('background-image')) {
      openCards.addClass('matched');
     } else {
      paused = true;
      setTimeout(function() {
        openCards.addClass('closed');
        paused = false;
      }, 1000);
   }
 }
});
```